# const char* not passing full filename

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, ifstream

I know there are a lot of questions similar to this, but I don't know of any that are the same, so here's my issue:

I'm trying to pass a filename as a const char * to my ifstream to read and load.

BUT: When I pass the filename, instead of reading the whole string "map.obj"; it just reads the first character "m" and as a result, the ifstream fails.

I don't know what I'm doing wrong and would appreciate a little help. My code follows:

```
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

void loadModel(const char* filename);

int main()
{
    // Creates and positions the four boxes on the screen. Temporary.
    //rotation r = {0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f};
    const char* filename = "map.obj";
    loadModel(filename);
    return 0;
    /*meshMgr.addObject(new Object());

    position p = {0.f, 10.f, 10.f};
    meshMgr.addObject(new Object(p, r));

    p.y = 0.f;
    p.z = 20.f;
    meshMgr.addObject(new Object(p, r));

    p.y = -10.f;
    p.z = 10.f;
    meshMgr.addObject(new Object(p, r));*/
}

void loadModel(const char* filename)
{
    ifstream in(filename, ios::in); //Open the model file
    if (in.is_open())   //if not opened, exit with -1
    {
        //Set up an array to act as a buffer for text read from the input file
        char buf[256];

        //Read input file text to end of file and push onto lines list
        while (!in.eof())
        {
            in.getline(buf, 256);
            //lines.push_back(new std::string(buf));
        }

        in.close();
    }
}
```

EDIT: Before anyone asks, yes the file is being referenced as a local file (do I need to use absolute paths or something?) and exists in the same directory as the source code

Comment: I think we need more code, because this looks okay.

Comment: can your reproduce it at ideone.com?

Comment: What makes you so sure that only the 1st character is passed to the function?? What makes you sure that `ifstream` constructor fails because of this??

Comment: And you're *sure* you're not accidentally casting-and-passing a wide-char name ?

Comment: Have you tried changing the declaration to const char filename[] = "map.obj" ?

Comment: @AndyG The problem is, it's this area of code that's causing the problem.

Comment: @g-makulik A little something called a Break Point

Comment: @Raisus And you'll see the 1st character in the debugger's memory view, right? But I'm pretty sure that the other characters are there. May be `ifstream()` fails, because you're not in the right working directory to access this file?? Did you try a full pathname?

Comment: @g-makulik That's right, but no, the other characters are not there, filename has a reference to a point in memory that contains the entire structure, but for whatever reason, filename itself only shows the first letter, and no, I'm using relative pathnames because it's in the same directory and I want to upload it to an SVN once it actually works

Comment: @mungflesh Yes, I did, it didn't change anything

Comment: @Raisus Then you're showing the wrong code example for your question. The reason is elsewhere, the code you've posted is OK and will work fine.

Comment: @Raisus This may be where your program is *failing*, but it may *not* be where the problem is caused.  For example, a rogue pointer might have overwritten part of filename somewhere else in the execution of your program.

Comment: Updated Question to show more code. Checked it on ideone.com, it says "Success"

Comment: @Eric I really thought so, but I can't find where

Comment: Did you run the code here (exactly) on your computer and see if it succeeds?

Comment: If your using c++11 why not use a string instead of a char array? they added a constructor that accepts strings

Comment: Does the code fail when constructing the ifstream or on your first getline call.  It appears you are trying to read an obj (binary) file as if it was text.

Comment: @Raisus _'and exists in the same directory as the source code'_ That's most probably not where you program is running. At least not if you're working with an IDE.

Comment: @Dweeberly it's binary? Maybe that's it. Hold on and I'll check. (Feel really stupid if it is)

Comment: @Dweeberly This would play a role only if the OP runs under Windows, for other OS that doesn't matter.

Comment: @Dweeberly it didn't help. 

It's whenever I switch between the main() and loadModel()

Comment: @Raisus Simply try a full path man! Just to ensure this isn't your problem.

Comment: @g-makulik arright. lemme go grab full path

Comment: @g-makulik it does the same with the full path, chops all but the first character off.

Comment: This really stinks like widechar stuff. Which compiler are you using?

Comment: Can you try ``const char filename[] = {109, 97, 112, 46, 111, 98, 106, 0};`` just for testing?

Comment: Can you update your question to show what exactly is shown in the debugger for that memory region `filename` points to? Are the other characters are stuffed with zeroes or garbage?

Comment: @JonasWielicki I'm using Visual Studio 2013's local debugger

Comment: @JonasWielicki it was worth a shot, using the numbers, but no dice

Comment: @g-makulik I wish (zeroes or garbage)

EDIT: No, I need more reputation to show images

Comment: @Raisus So again: If you can't see the memory region (your/any IDE/Debugger should be able to show you), what makes you so sure that there's only the 1st character passed??

Comment: _'No, I need more reputation to show images'_ Just reproduce it as text.

Comment: Okay... i fixed the passing error on my own, changing the value from const char * to string worked when passing. RESOLVED

EDIT: Actually, this was @thermite idea :D

Comment: @Raisus The newer c++11 standard allows to pass a `std::string` as argument to the `ifstream` constructor, but it shouldn't make a difference for the case you've been describing. Also I don't believe you've been hitting a compiler bug.

Comment: @g-makulik The bug is in fstream, figured out it's calling the wrong function, it calls const char * when it's supposed to be calling string, since my filename is now a string

Comment: @Raisus Could you post your findings & solution in an answer (if you don't mind the efforts)? I'd upvote it if it shows the problem. This might be useful for others.

Comment: @g-makulik Not for another 6 hours

Comment: @Raisus Of, course. I tend to forget about low rep restrictions in SO.

Comment: @g-makulik it sucks, but meh, that's SO for you.

I hate having to use fstream... =/ it's in there that it changes my nice lovely poignant string into a char "_Myt *open(const wstring& _Str,
  ios_base::openmode _Mode,
  int _Prot = (int)ios_base::_Openprot)
  { // open a wide-named C stream -- EXTENSION
  return (open(_Str.c_str(), _Mode, _Prot));
  }

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a very localized problem. The code is OK.

Comment: @KubaOber It probably is. I just got fustrated at the fact that for whatever cotrived reasoning, my code just did not want to open my file and thought that i might have been doing something wrong

Comment: At the end the crucial point seems to be `wstring` as @JonasWielicki already suspected.

Comment: @Raisus Now is the time ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a response to my own question, it appears that my code didn't like passing the variable that stored the filename as a cost char * when the data in the variable was stored in a string-like format.

To counteract this, I simply changed the code from:

```
int main ()
{
...
const char* filename = "map.obj";
loadModel(filename);
...
return 0;
}

void loadModel(const char* filename)
{
...
}
```

to the following:

```
int main ()
{
...
string filename = "map.obj";
loadModel(filename);
...
return 0;
}

void loadModel(string filename)
{
...
}
```

where "..." indicates more code as shown in the question.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you told in your comment: _'_Myt *open(const wstring& _Str, ios_base::openmode _Mode, int _Prot = (int)ios_base::_Openprot) { // open a wide-named C stream -- EXTENSION return (open(_Str.c_str(), _Mode, _Prot)); }' ..._ I think this (**wstring**) was the real cause of your problem

Answer (score 0):

This answers the error in the question, but begins with a string instead and uses a char instead of const char*.  It's an alternative solution.

> const char* not passing full filename

```
std::string filename = "map.obj";
char *cstr = new char[filename.length() + 1];
```